# How to use PHP glob() with minimum file date (filemtime)?

Tags: php, date, glob, filemtime

I want to get a range of files with PHP glob function, but no older than a month (or other specified date range).

My current code:

```
$datetime_min = new DateTime('today - 4 weeks');

$product_files = array();
foreach(glob($image_folder.$category_folder.'*'.$img_extension) as $key => $product) if (filemtime($product)>$datetime_min) { $product_files[] = $product; }
```

This returns an error:

> Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int

I think it still gives me a result with all files in that folder. So my approach could be completely wrong.

How can I make this code work, so I only have an array with files no older than the specified date?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are you sure this is in any way related to the usage of glob itself?

Comment: This seemed to have resolved it:
`$datetime = new DateTime('today - 4 weeks');`
`$datetime_min = $datetime->getTimestamp();`

The foreach and glob fuction I left unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`filemtime()` returns a Unix timestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime#refsect1-function.filemtime-returnvalues) which is an integer. DateTime objects are comparable but only to each other. You'll need either need to convert them into Unix timestamps or convert the result of `filemtime()` into a DateTime object.

Option 1:

```
$datetime = (new DateTime('now'))->format('U');
$datetime_min = (new DateTime('today - 4 weeks')->format('U');
```

Option 2:

```
$filetime = new DateTime(@filemtime($product));
if (filetime > $datetime_min) {}
```

Comment: Thanks John. Of course I should have realized the unix format :(. Although your code did threw me a server500 error. But with your timestamp suggestion I adapted it to this: '$datetime->getTimestamp();'
Now it runs without an error. But I can not check if it works until after a few days when there are files with different dates in that folder. :) Anyway. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just try this script

```php
<?php

$to = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-100 days"));

getAllFilesInDirectoryWithDateRange("*.*", $sdf, $today);

function getAllFilesInDirectoryWithDateRange($filePattern, $from, $to) {
    foreach (glob($filePattern) as $filename) {
        if (date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($filename)) >= $from &&
            date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($filename)) <= $to) {
                echo "$filename" . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
test4.txt
test5.txt
```

You can use `getAllFilesInDirectoryWithDateRange` function and get all file names in a directory 
In this function I use `filemtime` to get the time and then check the threshold like this

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($filename)) >= $from && 
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($filename)) <= $to
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php) for this problem.

```
$tsLimit = strtotime('-2 Month');
$file_pattern = ..//your file pattern

$files = array_filter(
  glob($file_pattern), 
  function($val) use($tsLimit){
    return filemtime($val) > $tsLimit;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use glob, it's inefficient to fetch results you'll never use, especially if the directory was huge.

Try instead:

```
exec("find $filePath -mtime -$days | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev", $results);
```

Because we don't always know the number of path separators, use cut with rev and the file is always the first entry.